# Gif Picture Not Able To Align?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Right now I am working with an iFrame for HTML and I am trying to center align this image. When I type in `align = "middle"` it doesn't seem to work. I wan to place this GIF in a website. Aligning it in the center would make it look nice.

```html
<iframe src="http://gifyoutube.com/embed/mG9rRw" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width='480' height='270' style="-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;-webkit-transform: scale(1);" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear if you want to center the img in the iframe, or in the entire window.

Comment: The image is what I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a GIF. That is a video (either MP4 or WebM (depending on your browser)) which is embedded in the iframe. It's so small and could easily be converted into a GIF, but that's not the question here.

Add this CSS to your iframe and it should align it in the middle horizontally.

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/odezpjLy/

Check out the JSFiddle above for an example.

Comment: You're right, I had converted the original video through an online converter.

Comment: @henleygarcia You should convert it to a GIF. Please mark my answer as correct if it was :)

Comment: I believe I marked it, I'm quite new here. Excuse my lack of knowledge around this site :p

Comment: @henleygarcia No problem haha. Usually you upvote + mark as answered on the answered post, and if something else worked, you can upvote that as well. But only 1 answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Place it in a `div` wrapper, and center the item in the `<div>`:

```css
#wrapper
{
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<iframe src="http://gifyoutube.com/embed/mG9rRw" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width='480' height='270' style="-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;-webkit-transform: scale(1);" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a hacky way and shouldn't be used. You should avoid `width: 100%` at all cost, if you can use `margin: 0 auto` instead. Also, adding a DIV around it just complicates things more.